# Why is html-minifier telling me : Unknown option `--minifyJS'?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, minify

**QUESTION:**

I installed `uglify-js` globally and I installed `html-minifier`.

Minification of HTML works fine but when I add `--minifyJS` to minify javascript as well, it fails with the following error:

```
  error: unknown option `--minifyJS'
```

What have I done wrong ?

---

**CODE:**

```
html-minifier --input-dir ./viewsCopy --output-dir ./views-minified --collapse-whitespace --html5 --minifyJS
```

---

**REFERENCE:**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-minifier

---

**OUTPUT**

```
<% include ../partials/header %> <div class="backgroundLogin"><div class="alertMessage"> <% if (errors.length > 0) { for (var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {%> <div class="alert alert-danger"> <%= errors[i].msg %> </div> <% } }%> </div><div class="alertMessage"><span class="alert alert-success containerMargins" id="successDiv"></span> <span class="alert alert-danger containerMargins" id="errorDiv"></span></div><div class="alertMessage"> <% if (success_msg != false){ %> <span class="alert alert-success containerMargins"> <%= success_msg %> </span> <% } %> <% if (error_msg != false){ %> <span class="alert alert-danger containerMargins"> <%= error_msg %> </span> <% } %> </div><div class="containerMargins"><h1 class="authTitle">Login</h1><form id="loginForm"><div class="form-group"><label>Email</label><input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="loginEmail" placeholder="You can't forget it :)" required></div><div class="form-group"><label>Password</label><input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="loginPassword" placeholder="We hope you didn't forget it ^^" required minlength="12"></div><div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcRrxMUAAAAANx-AXSdRLAo4Pyqfqg-1vuPSJ5c"></div><button class="btn btn-default" id="loginButton">Submit</button> <span class="userLinks"><a class="logLinks" href="/users/register">Register</a><a href="/users/password">Password?</a></span></form></div></div> <% include ../partials/indexScripts %> <script>$("#loginForm").submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault(); 
    var email = $("#loginEmail").val();
    var password = $("#loginPassword").val();

    $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "login",
        data: $this.serialize()
    }).done(function(data) {

        if (data == true) {

            firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password ).then( authData => {

                var pendingRef = firebase.database().ref('pending/'+authData.uid.toString());
                var userRef =firebase.database().ref('users/'+authData.uid.toString());

                pendingRef.once('value', function(snapshot){

                    if(snapshot.val() == null) {

                        localStorage.setItem("success_msg_local2", "You have logged in");
                        ("Success1 ");
                        window.location.href="/fun/index";

                    } else {
                        if (authData.emailVerified) {

                            userRef.set(snapshot.val());
                            pendingRef.remove();

                            localStorage.setItem('success_msg_local2', 'You have logged in');
                            ("Success2");

                            window.location.href="/fun/index";
                        }

                        else {

                            firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
                                localStorage.setItem('error_msg_local', 'Please confirm your email address. Check your inbox.');
                                window.location.href="/users/login";
                                ("Login Failed: ", error);

                            }, function(error) {

                            });
                        }

                    }
                });

            },function(error) { 

                var errorCode = error.code;
                var errorMessage = error.message;
                localStorage.setItem('error_msg_local', "Unknown user or password");
                window.location.href="/users/login";
                ("Login Failed: ", errorMessage, errorCode);

            });  
        }
        else {
            localStorage.setItem('error_msg_local',  'Recaptcha failed'); window.location.href = "/users/login";
        }
    });
});</script>
```

Comment: Just a guess, but you may need to have UglifyJS installed? https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2

Comment: @LennartHase Did you read the first line of my question :D ?

Comment: `npm link .` on Windows restart system - PATH vars are changed probably

Comment: @DanielMizerski Directories paths are fine, they work for HTML minification.

Comment: @Coder1000 nope, I'm an idiot, sorry :P

Comment: @LennartHase No, you're human :D

Comment: What if the option isn't prefixed with double dash?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I have no idea :/ Shoudl I remove the double dashes ?

Comment: @evolutionxbox nope. Double dashes are necessary for options or they are treated as paths apparently

Comment: From the `--help` of html-minifier `--minify-js [value]                  Minify Javascript in script elements and on* attributes (uses uglify-js)` the modifier is slightly different, should be `--minify-js` instead of `--minifyJS` that you're using above

Comment: @LennartHase Great ! Now it does not throw an error, but my js is not minified :/ Hmmm

Comment: did you put `true` as the value?

Comment: @LennartHase Actually, the js is minified, but not when it's jquery, hmmm

Comment: @LennartHase I did.

Comment: @LennartHase I cannot conceive jQuery being treated differently. This makes no sense, it's javascript after all.

Comment: Ran a quick test script, uglifyJS is compressing jQuery fine

Comment: @LennartHase Then what is happening ? Have a look at the output I get (question updated)

Comment: @Coder1000 curiously, it works fine if the jQuery is put in a separate file, but not when it's part of the HTML, no idea why? Maybe a bug in html-minifier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a look at the documentation it would appear that the command should be `--minifyJS`, however, I had a quick look at the `--help` page for `html-minifier` and it indicates the following;

```
--minify-js [value] Minify Javascript in script elements and on* attributes (uses uglify-js)
```

Where `[value]` should be set to `true`.

Sor your final command should be

```
html-minifier --input-dir ./viewsCopy --output-dir ./views-minified --collapse-whitespace --html5 --minify-js true
```

Appears this won't compress jQuery if part of an HTML file, so it might be beneficial to put the javascript in an external file, or maybe alternative minifiers may be able to achieve what you desire.